# Inverse Laplace transform via the table formulas

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

In my inverse Laplace table there is this inversion "formula":

$(1) \frac{1}{s-a} \rightarrow e^{at}$

I understand that

$\mathcal{L}^{-1}[\frac{1}{s+4}] = \frac{1}{2}\sin(2t)$

But why can I not do the following:

$\mathcal{L}^{-1}[\frac{1}{s+4}] = \mathcal{L}^{-1}[\frac{1}{s-(-4)}]$

Using $(1): \mathcal{L}^{-1}[\frac{1}{s-(-4)}]=e^{-4t}$?

Comment: Who said you couldn't?  BTW Your second inverse transform is wrong.

Comment: Aha, now I understand. I mixed up $s$ and $s^2$! Ugh! Thank you, Gordon!

Comment: Inversion formula (1) is incorrect.  Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to understand what is going on with the inverse Laplace transform. The inverse Laplace transform is
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\} = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}F(s)e^{st}ds =\sum\operatorname{Res}\{F(s);s_j\}
$$
where the residues are the poles of $F(s)$. With your first equation, we have a pole when $s = a$; that is, division by zero. The pole is of order one since we have $1/(s-a)^1$. Now, let's find the inverse Laplace transform
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{1/(s-a)\}=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{e^{st}}{s-a}ds =\lim_{s\to a}(s-a)\frac{e^{st}}{s-a}=e^{at}
$$
Now you seem to have some confusion with your next ILT. Again, let's tackle this by definition.
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{1/(s+4)\}=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{e^{st}}{s+4}ds =\lim_{s\to -4}(s+4)\frac{e^{st}}{s+4}=e^{-4t}
$$
In order to obtain $1/2\sin(2t)$, we need $F(s) = \frac{1}{s^2+4}$. Let's prove this to ourselves. In the case, $s^2+4=(s-2i)(s+2i)$ so we have two simple poles of order one at $s=\pm 2i$.
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{1/(s^2+4)\}&=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty}\frac{e^{st}}{s^2+4}ds\\ 
&=\lim_{s\to -2i}(s+2i)\frac{e^{st}}{s^2+4}+\lim_{s\to 2i}(s-2i)\frac{e^{st}}{s^2+4}\tag{1}\\
&=\frac{e^{-2it}}{-4i}+\frac{e^{2it}}{4i}\tag{2}
\end{align}
In equation $(1)$, you see we summed the two residues. Now to reduce equation $(2)$, we just need to recall a trig identity. That is,
$$
\sin(t) = \frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2i}
$$
so equation $(2)$ is really $1/2\sin(2t)$.

Comment: I don't know what to say except "wow" and "thanks" here, so I'll stick to that. Fantastic! Thank you for using your time to explain this!

Comment: @Akitirija do you understand how poles work? Try to take the ILT of $$\frac{s+4}{s^2(s^2+4)}$$ and report back with your answer. If you get this right, you have a decent handle on the method.

Comment: I will try, but I cannot guarantee any success here.

Comment: I've tried reading about the complex inversion formula in a book called "The Laplace Transform Theory and Applications" by Joel Schiff, which by the way is a great book on the subject of Laplace. I find it very interesting, but I feel like I have to read more about "complex theory" in order to understand this.

Comment: @Akitirija yes and no. To do the basic Laplace transforms for an ODE class, not really. To really understand it, yes. If your goal is to be free of tables, it should be fine and can pick pieces up as you go. If you look at my answers in the Laplace transform tag, you may find examples that help as well.

Comment: @Akitirija I looked up the book you mention and found a pdf of it online. I plan posting my solutions to it. If you go to my profile, you will see a link to my github there is where I will post the solutions. I have already read the first two chapters.

Comment: I do not know how to thank you enough, that is just amazing! I've already seen your first work there. I plan on spending time during the summer expanding my knowledge of the Laplace and Fourier transform. Your solution guide will come in helpful then.